# Compile and link OpenCV to my project in my main CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am new to cmake. I have a project which uses dlib and opencv. They are defined as submodules which are in third_party folder. I want to link them to my main project which is 'node' with cmake but I could not achieved. I am sharing my project tree. I did with find_package(OpenCV) and target_link_libraries(recognition-node ${OPENCV_LIBS}) way but I need to compile from source without installing anything. At last, I just want to write 'cmake . && make'

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── node
│   ├── build.sh
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── configure.sh
│   ├── findfacestask.cpp
│   ├── findfacestask.h
│   ├── main.cpp
│   ├── matrixwrapper.h
│   ├── poolcontext.cpp
│   ├── poolcontext.h
│   ├── recognition.dat
│   ├── recognizefacetask.cpp
│   ├── recognizefacetask.h
│   ├── runscript
│   ├── sp.dat
│   ├── task.cpp
│   ├── task.h
│   ├── unhandledexception.cpp
│   ├── unhandledexception.h
│   ├── webcamfeed.cpp
│   ├── webcamfeed.h
│   ├── wrapper.cpp
│   └── wrapper.h
└── third_party
    ├── dlib
    │   ├── appveyor.yml
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── dlib
    │   ├── docs
    │   ├── examples
    │   ├── MANIFEST.in
    │   ├── python_examples
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── setup.py
    │   └── tools
    └── opencv
        ├── 3rdparty
        ├── apps
        ├── cmake
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
        ├── data
        ├── doc
        ├── include
        ├── LICENSE
        ├── modules
        ├── platforms
        ├── README.md
        └── samples
```

Content of my top CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory(node)
add_subdirectory(third_party/dlib)
add_subdirectory(third_party/opencv)
```

Content of node/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(recognition-node)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(recognition-node main.cpp  
            webcamfeed.cpp 
            poolcontext.cpp 
            unhandledexception.cpp
            task.cpp
            findfacestask.cpp
            wrapper.cpp
            recognizefacetask.cpp)

target_link_libraries(recognition-node Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(recognition-node dlib::dlib)
target_link_libraries(recognition-node opencv::core)
```

It gives error in 'make' stage which is :

```
/home/arnes/workspace/recognition-node/node/poolcontext.h:10:28: fatal error: 
opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like `opencv::*` targets, created by OpenCV project, doesn't bonded with their include directories. So you need to include these directories manually, with `include_directories` or `target_include_directories`. In the OpenCV source tree find the file `opencv2/core.hpp` and include directory, which contains this file.

Comment: I thought what you said but if i linked to header files in source code, it's structure are different, so I don't want mismatch. Another addition, if I compile and install OpenCV standalone it copies required header files and libraries to system folders. According to this, there is a appropriate way to include those folders, but i dont know how to :)

Comment: So you want to compile OpenCV each time your build your project? or you have a global system wide OpenCV installation.

Comment: Please answer a few questions: 1. can you have your OpenCV compiled and installed locally (e.g. in your user's home dir)? if not - every time you compile your project, you waste time to compile OpenCV; 2. same question for dlib; 3. why do you want to execute `cmake .`? usually it is `cmake ..` from the `build ` directory; 4. why don't you use any `target_include_directories`?

Comment: Actually, I was intended to write ''cmake ..'' but forgot a dot. I 
can use pre-installed, a global system wide opencv packages as you said. It is easier way but I just want it to do in this way. There is no strong point to build whole dependencies from source.

Comment: OpenCV doesn't provide any include_dir variable when it is just included in the build tree and install procedure is not invoked. That's why by default your module doesn't see the headers. You can of course hack it and add all the `opencvDir/modules/[xxx]/include` to your `target_include_directories`, but I don't see the point. Having OpenCV in your project build tree seems like a terrible idea to me. Conclusion: you can do as you wanted initially, but it is not trivial and efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you insist on keeping the opencv in your project tree

> It is easier way but I just want it to do in this way.

Here is the solution that for sure works fine with your project tree that you posted in the question and with [opencv-3.4.1](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.4.1). For simplicity I will neglect `dlib` library and `Qt` dependency, since you didn't have any problem with it.

Root `CMakeLists.txt` should have the following content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11) # or anything higher, if you wish
project(recognition-node CXX)

add_subdirectory(node)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` under the `node` directory should have the following content:

```
add_subdirectory(third_party)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -g") # or any other additional flags

# at this point you can add find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED) and later link your binary against Qt5::widgets as well
add_executable(myExec main.cpp
# and put here all the other source files of your project ...
)
# for linking libs I have put additionally highgui and imgproc to check the solution against OpenCV official sample
target_link_libraries(myExec opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc)

target_include_directories(myExec PUBLIC 
    third_party/opencv/modules/calib3d/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/core/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudaarithm/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudabgsegm/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudacodec/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudafeatures2d/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudafilters/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudaimgproc/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudalegacy/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudaobjdetect/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudaoptflow/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudastereo/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudawarping/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/cudev/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/dnn/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/features2d/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/flann/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/highgui/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/imgproc/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/ml/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/objdetect/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/photo/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/shape/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/stitching/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/superres/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/ts/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/video/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/videoio/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/videostab/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/viz/include
    third_party/opencv/modules/world/include
)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` under `third_party` should contain only:

```
add_subdirectory(opencv)
# add_subdirectory(dlib) # if you will use dlib, of course also add dlib
```

The sample I used to verify the build is [contours2.cpp](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d0/d2a/contours2_8cpp-example.html) (just copy pasted the content into `main.cpp`).

However, I still think that it is a terrible idea to use this solution.

- OpenCv takes really a lot of time to compile
- you have to manually add include dirs (you can use some macro generators, but usually it looks even more ugly)
- in your build system you have a lot of targets (over 300) that you don't really need, including `install` target

So, my recommendation is: if you want, use this solution for scientific purpose, but just compile and install OpenCv system-wise (or locally, if you are not the admin) when you really need to use it.

Comment: There are plenty of valid reasons to compile OpenCV manually and keep it in the project tree. Mobile apps or embedded devices will need cross-compiled version with specific options set.