# How do I include RealSense2/OpenCV source into compilation with CMake?

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, cmake, realsense

### **SHORT VERSION**

I want to bundle the (uncompiled) source files for OpenCV and librealsense2 with CMake so I can cross compile it on RPi (or at all), but I am new to CMake and don't know how.

```
add_executable (CMakeRealSense "CMakeRealSense.cpp" "CMakeRealSense.h")

include_directories(opencv libs/opencv-master/include)
include_directories(realsense2 libs/librealsense-master/include)
```

This gives a bunch of errors related to RS files itself (X not declared on scope).

### **LONG VERSION**

I am currently attempting to write a program for the Intel RealSense camera d435. There are two libraries I am using. OpenCV and librealsense2 (actual library for the camera). I first used VCPKG to load the packages in, and that works for my local machine, but I can't properly compile it on the RPi 3. I decided that bundling source files with the project would be good idea, but I can't get it to work. I'm getting one error after another.

#### EDIT 1

When I compile on my local windows machine I get error `Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp': No such file or directory`. And, on my pi it gives a bunch of errors related to RealSense files themselves (didn't check them all, there where 780 of them)

#### EDIT 3

As pointed out by @squareskittles. I fixed the issue relating to my local windows version, but for the pi I still have issues with new errors.

From what I can tell the error states that it can't find the `opengl_config.cmake` folder in folders `tools`, `src` and `examples` (`examples` will be removed down the line so not much of a issue). Last error is

```
CMake Error at libs/librealsense-master/CMake/install_config.cmake:4 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "uninstall" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
  created in source directory
  "/home/pi/.vs/CMakeRealSense/d6128cea-ef93-4c7b-83bb-89ee6315963f/src/libs/opencv-master".
  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
```

#### EDIT 4

So I firstly just added the cmake folder containing the install config and that works how, the 2nd error how ever seems to be that both `librealsense` and `opencv` have the same name in the uninstall config. Can the `add_custom_target` for uninstall be safely changed without effecting the rest of the cmake building process?

#### EDIT 5

It succesfully compiles the realsense2 libraries (as far as I can tell) but it cant open the `opencv2/core.hpp` source file. Not sure why it cant find it.

#### EDIT 6

So I did ALOT more digging and aperently opencv uses a header file to check which modules your using, [problem is it doesnt properly generate one](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/templates/opencv_modules.hpp.in). I am not sure how to do this but ill do some more digging to find out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think the command you're looking for is `add_subdirectory()` to tell CMake to go into each of the `opencv` and `realsense2` directories, and configure those as well.

Comment: @squareskittles this did it fix for the windows compilation(big thanks btw) but not yet for the pi version, ill edit the post to reflect this

Comment: Some of the issues (and fixes) related to including OpenCV source in your project are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422351/compile-and-link-opencv-to-my-project-in-my-main-cmakelists-txt).

Comment: I saw that post before but it confused me as I read it. Probably my lack of experiance with it. Ill try to give it another glance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the OpenCV and RealSense2 source in your CMake project directly, you should use the [`add_subdirectory()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) command to tell CMake to look in each of the directories. Be sure to provide the path to the **top-level** CMakeLists.txt file in each of the other source repositories, or they will not be configured completely:

```
add_subdirectory(libs/opencv-master)
add_subdirectory(libs/librealsense-master)
```

Later on in your CMakeLists.txt file, you need to make use of the CMake variables and targets defined in each of these sub-repositories in order to include each of these libraries in **your** executable. For example:

```
# Define your CMake executable target.
add_executable(CMakeRealSense CMakeRealSense.cpp CMakeRealSense.h)

# Link the OpenCV components and RealSense targets to your executable target.
target_link_libraries(CMakeRealSense PRIVATE opencv_core realsense2)
```

You may also have to link additional OpenCV components, such as `opencv_imgproc`, `opencv_dnn`, `opencv_imgcodecs`, `opencv_videoio`, `opencv_highgui`, etc, depending on what OpenCV functionality you are using.

Comment: This probably is what I needed, but its not quiet the fix yet. I still have the same errors as described in edit 3

Comment: @Autism This is one of the drawbacks of including these external libraries in your own source tree, you can run into naming conflicts. You'll have to rename one of the custom targets (to something like `opencv_uninstall`) and rebuild. Also, if you are missing header files, you may have to manually add the paths to the missing headers: `target_include_directories(CMakeRealSense PRIVATE libs/opencv-master/modules/core/include)`

Comment: The error changed that it cant include ```opencv2/opencv_module.hpp``` in ```opencv.hpp```. But thanks for guiding me along the way!