# Cant compile OpenCV Source file with my project

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

[This question is a continuation of one I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389563/how-do-i-include-realsense2-opencv-source-into-compilation-with-cmake)

I have a project that uses the librealsense library and OpenCV. librealsense works but I cannot include OpenCV in my project for the life of me. There is currently only 1 CPP file and 1 HPP file, this is the cmake file of the root

```
project(peoplecounting)


add_subdirectory(libs/librealsense-master)
add_subdirectory(libs/opencv-4.3.0)

set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs/opencv-4.3.0)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable (CMakeRealSense "CMakeRealSense.cpp" "CMakeRealSense.h")
find_library(realsense2 HINTS libs/librealsense-master)
find_library(opencv HINTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs/opencv-4.3.0)

target_link_libraries(CMakeRealSense ${OpenCV_LIBS} realsense2)

I have both source files in a libs folder(so directory would look like root/libs/opencv-4.3.0). I am new to cmake so I just might be missing something but its driving me nuts
```

Some extra notes

1, OpenCV does build the libs when I can build the project, if I remove any include from my self written code it wont make errors which lets me build the project. This does make the opencv librairys which makes me think the linking is the issue

2, If I dont add a project as a executable it does see a opencv include

3, I am doing this to make the project portable, it has to work on a rpi down the line so being able to build it all from source could make it much more portable

#### EDIT 1

So I did some diging in my files, the exe gets outputted into 
`root\out\build\x64-Debug\bin` but this folder does not only contain the librealsense dll but also the opencv ones. This would make it seem that the exe knows about the library but doesnt want to use it some how? This is very strange to me too

#### EDIT 2

I managed to `find_package(OpenCV)` by setting
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to win-install which contained a config file, problem now is that iam missing the include dir in said folder

#### EDIT 3

New error seems to be

```
  Target "opencv_highgui" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains
  path:

    "root/opencv-4.3.0/modules/dnn/include"

  which is prefixed in the source directory.
```

I read somewhere that OpenCV prevents source files being used or something to prevent corruption but now now again at a end when it comes to what iam suppose to be doing

Updated CMake file

````
project(peoplecounting)


add_subdirectory(librealsense-master)
add_subdirectory(opencv-4.3.0)

set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/")
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)


find_package(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_library(opencv INTERFACE)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})


#add_executable (CMakeRealSense "CMakeRealSense.cpp" "CMakeRealSense.h")
add_executable(RealSenseTest "TestRealSense.cpp")
find_library(realsense2 HINTS librealsense-master)

message(" cv_libs: " ${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}) 
message(" cv_includes: " ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(opencv INTERFACE "${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
target_link_libraries(RealSenseTest "${OpenCV_LIBS}" realsense2)```
````

Comment: You may check [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#create-a-cmake-file) and [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk the first source does not work for me, CMake cant find the OpenCV package for me, the 2nd one doesnt work for me either since I want to build it all at the same time, I dont want to have to build the librairy first and then try and shoe horn it in. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @nayab ```opencv2/core.hpp not found``` and errors relating to that(X not defined, which would be defined there)

Comment: add these lines to check if the cmake found libs and include files: message(" cv_libs:     " ${OpenCV_LIBS})
message(" cv_includes: " ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

Comment: @nayab Output is```1> [CMake]  cv_libs: 
1> [CMake]  cv_includes: ```. I assume that means its empty. Il try to figure out where these vars where suppose to point to, thanks for the tip

Comment: I guess OpenCV_DIR is also set wrong, please check it message(" OpenCV_DIR: " ${OpenCV_DIR}).

Comment: @nayab To what should it be set? If I set it to the build error I get a bunch of errors saying "Target "opencv_core" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:

    "E:/projects/OpenCV.CMake/out/build/x64-Debug"

  which is prefixed in the build directory." errors. If I set it to the opencv folder I get missing config error

Comment: OpenCV_DIR must be the folder conataining cmake files like "OpenCVConfig.cmake, OpenCVConfig.cmake  OpenCVConfig-version.cmake  OpenCVModules.cmake  OpenCVModules-release.cmake"

Comment: Multiple dir contain these files, if I do it in the build root or the opencv folder they give the same error, in win-install it gives a error that there is no include folder